# Given $a,b,c$ solve $1=x^a + x^b - x^c$ for $x$

Tags: exponentiation

If $a,b,c$ are constants, is it possible to isolate $x$ in the following equation?

$$1 = x^a + x^b - x^c$$

If so, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean, *solve* for $x$? If so, there are no general methods.

Comment: I think he wants a general formula for $x$.

Comment: @lhf yes. Thanks - if you post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ positive? It's not hard to find $x$ numerically, given $a,b,c$. The only slightly tricky thing is avoiding the trivial solution $x=1$.

Comment: Unfortunately not, in my use-case both $b$ and $c$ are negative

Comment: What about the sign of a ? Besides, are $a,b,c$ integer or real ?

Comment: Can you give me a typical set of $a,b,c$ so I can test how well my strategy works?

Comment: $a$ is always positive. All of $a,b,c,x$ are real. I will collect a set of $a,b,c,x$ for you.

Comment: @PM2Ring here's a sample: $a=0.1, b=-18, c=-17$. This should give $x=e$ if I've done my stuff right.

Comment: $a = 0.1, b=-14.42419, c=-13.42419$, giving $x=e^{0.1}$

Comment: I've just calculated these forwards and got a value of $1.105170$ for both of them (they should give $1$). I'm getting my values from a program I am currently writing so I must have made a mistake somewhere, I wouldn't expect a 10% inaccuracy here.

Comment: Thanks. As I suspected, the $x=1$ solution causes problems for a simple Newton's Method approach. I'll have to think about this...

Comment: Ok. For (0.1, -18, -17) I get $x=0.14024358282171$. Here'a a [Sage / Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdkNEKwjAMRd_3FRefOtep8UUZFvySQdt1UoQptUL396abbGIe0tzm3EBy9UN0QdtYdK5HdK8otDrsSMKoms4Slp-TRFK0o7IpwJHJXqSvyhFcfIcBqdWoOBvUnO3UnlL_CPDwA4Iebk7Q4cc7QkHkcWyiEnuINFUL0DGgt6kVeiYqmKzMrGrYrOyfJ-WpaRlJXHVcjCuSUCnmFv0MfArhJTbNhveVGCW3V9730OYl-AsXkKvp2MAEp-_F6mZX3qT8ANQWTo0=&lang=sage) using Newton's method. It needs a good initial approximation for $x$. To run it in plain Python, change all `^` to `**`.

Comment: @PM2Ring This works great! Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: No worries. There might be a good way to produce a good initial approximation, but simple trial & error seems to work ok. ;)